# How to find centroid/ orthogonal using vectors?

Tags: vectors

The answer to this question is option D in my textbook but I think all the options are correct. This question was asked in IIT ADV 2017.

[image]

Comment: How can they all be correct? The four points are in general distinct for arbitrary triangles. So if you have checked that $S$ is always unique, it can only be one of the points, in general.

Comment: What if the triangle is an equilateral one? I can prove that option A and D is correct and that is only possible when PQR is an equilateral triangle. @57Jimmy

Comment: It's an *arbitrary triangle* !!

Comment: I can prove that option A and D is correct and that is only possible when PQR is an equilateral triangle. @TedShifrin

Comment: @raajsuriya Of course in an equilateral triangle all the answers will be true, because they are the same. But you need to find an answer that is always valid. And there can be at most one of them that is always valid, because in general the points are all distinct. Your proof that [A] is always valid must be wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you manipulate the algebra, you'll find that
$$\overrightarrow{PS}\cdot\overrightarrow{RQ} = \overrightarrow{QS}\cdot\overrightarrow{PR}= \overrightarrow{RS}\cdot\overrightarrow{PQ}= 0.$$
This tells us that $S$ is the intersection of the altitudes of $\triangle PQR$.